# libxml/xmlversion.h file not found in windows

Tags: c, xml

I want to do XMLParsing in c(windows). for that i need the libxml/xmlversion.h file. so can any one please tell me how to find or include the file in visual studio 2008.

thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the complete libxml library (including the include files) from [the downloads section at the libxml website](http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html). A Windows binary version of the libraries (so you won't have to compile the library itself) is available from [the maintainer of the windows port](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html).